# React Native & MobX: useContext doesn't re-render the change into the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, mobx, use-context

I have been trying to use mobX to apply on React Native Functional Component.
So I use these 2 libraries - mobx & mobx-react-lite.

I made a simple counter app and I also useContext hook along with this.
After increasing the value, it doesn't apply on the screen. However, it appeared on my console.
The change got displayed on after I had refreshed my code by saving it (I didn't change the code)

How do I solve this issue?

App.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import { CounterStoreContext } from './components/CounterStore';
  
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

const App = observer(() => {
  // const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const counterStore = useContext(CounterStoreContext)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Just Press the damn button</Text>
      {/* <Text style={styles.text}>{count}</Text> */}
      {/* <Button title="Increase" onPress={()=>{setCount(count+1)}}/> */}
      <Text style={styles.text}>{counterStore.count}</Text>
      <Button title="Increase" onPress={()=>{
        counterStore.count++;
        console.log(counterStore.count)
        // setCount(counterStore.count)
      }}/>      
    </View>
  );
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  welcome:{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  text:{
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

CounterStore.js

```
import { observable, observe } from "mobx";
import { createContext } from "react";

class CounterStore {
    @observable count = 0;
}

export const CounterStoreContext = createContext(new CounterStore())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since MobX 6 the `@observable` decorator is not enough](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html). You need to use [`makeObservable`](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html) / [`makeAutoObservable`](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html) in the constructor as well.

```
class CounterStore {
    @observable count = 0;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: "as well" is confusing here... you're meant to do one or the other.  makeObservable was conceived of at a time before decorators had made it into the Typescript spec.  So if you're suggesting that that decorators w mobx are broken (for some other reason), it might be better to say, "just use the makeObservable / makeAutoObservable API"